# How does WhatsApp synchronize messages between phone and web browser or computer application?

Tags: encryption

I would like to learn about message synchronization process of whatsapp cross platform applications for same user.
I've checked [WA whitepaper](https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t39.8562-34/122249142_469857720642275_2152527586907531259_n.pdf/WA_Security_WhitePaper.pdf?ccb=1-4&_nc_sid=2fbf2a&_nc_ohc=oGemfWdOYmUAX_tHAwO&_nc_ht=scontent.whatsapp.net&oh=20e44878fe722bf3c24ad4995ea648d4&oe=61123DD9) and couldn't see any explanation.

I'm using both WA WebApp and Phone App at the same time.
To achive end to end encryption do my phone and web app create different tunnels between my contacts (which doesn't make any sense, because it can synchronize my older messages) or WA creates another tunnel between my phone and WebApp which can not be accepted as "end to end encryption" because when I send a message from my webApp it should be decrypted at my phone then to be encrypted and send to my contact.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that WhatsApp Web works by establishing a secure channel to your phone and then it simply fetches data from the phone / sends instructions to the phone, preserving end-to-end encryption. No reference for that statement though (yet).